# Camera zooms in on preview and zooms out when taking a picture

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspicam

[VIDEO](https://youtu.be/0L84-zSVpso)

This is the script I run

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime

from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.rotation = 180
#camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
#camera.annotate_text = str(datetime.now().time())

camera.start_preview()

for i in range(5):
        sleep(5)
        camera.capture('tst/img%02d.png' % i)

camera.stop_preview()
```

When the preview starts the camera is quite zoomed in but when it takes a picture it zooms out and the picture is zoomed out.

Why is it zooming in and what can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you're describing looks a lot like [this one](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/23) described on the PiCamera Github page. User waveform80, who maintains the library, provided this explanation back in 2013:

> ...the only time the preview matches the capture area at the moment is
>   when the camera's resolution is set to maximum (2592x1944). At any
>   resolution other than that, the preview is drawn from the 1920x1080
>   pixels at the centre of the camera's sensor (the "video area") and
>   scaled to the requested resolution, while the capture uses the full
>   area (scaled down to the requested resolution). That's what the bit at
>   the end of the Preview vs Still Resolution is going on about.
>   Unfortunately this just seems to be an artifact of the way the preview
>   port of the camera works.

The discussion there leads to [this example](https://github.com/russb78/pi-mation/blob/38e32a800f9dee9fc4aca1748bd1ad0bfb620df0/pi-mation/pi-mation.py#L36), again on Github, which seems to work around the problem through appending the `use_video_port = True` option to the camera.capture() command.

Comment: Thanks, ```use_video_port```  doesn't do what I want though, when I run with it - it always shows the preview size without zooming out, but I want to always see the zoomed out version, in which the picture will be taken. 

I'll accept this though, since it doesn't seem like there is a solution.

Comment: I think you're probably right, although it might be worth tinkering with setting the camera resolution to its maximum per the quoted comment in my answer. It seems to be suggesting that setting to max resolution will render the preview at full size (I think).

Comment: I'm planning on setting it up without a screen and sending stills to my laptop anyway, so it doesn't bother me that much that the zoom is changing, just a little weird now that I'm testing it.

Comment: Yes - when capturing with the still port (when `use_video_port=False`, the default), the camera's firmware performs a temporary mode switch to [mode 2 or 3](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html#sensor-modes) while performing the capture. If you force that mode (with `sensor_mode` in the constructor, or by selecting an appropriate res + framerate) you won't get the "zoom". However, beware that on the V2 module you [can't run the preview at full res](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/faq.html#preview-flickers-at-full-resolution-on-a-v2-module)

Answer (score 1):

you can show the display preview indicating the weight and height as follows:
raspivid -t 0 -fps 25 -w 640 -h 480

Change the resolution as you prefer.